# Failed to call IResourceEventListener.resourceChangeEventEnd java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, eclipse

when I start eclipse ide.. An exception comes

Failed to call IResourceEventListener.resourceChangeEventEnd
java.lang.StackOverflowError

How to resolve it..
Can anyone help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old question, but maybe it will be useful for someone. In my case, this error was caused by importing R file from library project. Some class from library project B was moved to project A(which uses B), but it still had import from previous package

> package com.something.projectA
>
> import com.something.projectB.R

Solution: Use proper R for project